# Why my latex footer is not at the bottem of my page?

Tags: latex, size, footer, pdflatex

I want to write a lesson with lateX but my preamble with my footer have a big problem.

All my preambule work but, my footers is not on the page,. Could yu help me?

This is my  preambule.sty

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{%
  detect-family,
  exponent-product = \cdot,
  number-unit-separator=\text{\,},
  output-decimal-marker={\text{,}}
} %unités
\usepackage[margin=0.7in, bottom=1.5in, top=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}  % Chargement du package TikZ
\usepackage{xcolor}  % Chargement du package de couleurs

\definecolor{maincolor}{HTML}{33000A}%bordeaux
\definecolor{second}{HTML}{004953}%vert minuit
\definecolor{third}{HTML}{191970}%bleue nuit
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{my name}
\fancyhead[C]{my title}
\fancyhead[R]{\today}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{\color{second}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Supprime la ligne de séparation du pied de page

\fancyfoot[R]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \fill[second!55]
          (current page.south west) rectangle ++ (\paperwidth+4cm, 4.5cm);
        \fill[second!80]
          (current page.south east) --++ (0,6) to[out=-110,in=10] ++ (-6,-3.5) -- cycle;
        \node at (current page.south) [circle,fill=second!20, yshift=0.9cm, scale=1.5] {\LARGE\thepage}; % Ajustez cette valeur pour déplacer le bas de page
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}



\RequirePackage[french,english]{babel}

\RequirePackage{multirow,graphicx}
\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{vmargin}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs}
\RequirePackage{esint}

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{pdfpages}

\let\divsymb=\div
\let\vector=\vec %\vector donne des flèches maintenant

%\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} %\vec donne des vecteurs en gras
\newcommand{\uni}[1]{\widehat{\boldsymbol{#1}}} %Vecteur unitaire (grec autorisé)
%\newcommand{\uni}[1]{\widehat{\vec{#1}}} %Vecteur unitaire


%%Opérateurs différentiels en toutes lettres
\newcommand{\grad}{\overrightarrow{\text{grad} \,}} 
\renewcommand{\div}{\text{div} \,}
\newcommand{\rot}{\overrightarrow{\text{rot}} \,} 

\newcommand{\diff}[2]{\displaystyle \frac{d#1}{d#2}}
\newcommand{\ddiff}[2]{\displaystyle \frac{d^2#1}{d#2^2}}
\newcommand{\pdiff}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\newcommand{\pddiff}[2]{\displaystyle \frac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial #2^2}}
\newcommand{\thermodiff}[3]{\displaystyle \left.\pdiff{#1}{#2}\right|_{#3}}

\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left| #1 \right|}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\| #1 \|} 
\newcommand{\moy}[1]{\left< #1 \right>}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\alph{subsubsection}}
\subsubsectionfont{\normalfont\itshape}

\setmarginsrb{2cm}{1cm}{2cm}{1cm}{1cm}{1cm}{1cm}{1cm}

\newtheoremstyle{base}{0pt}{3pt}{}{}{\bfseries}{ : }{0pt}{}
\theoremstyle{base} %Environnements thm de base
\newtheorem{defi}{Définition}
\surroundwithmdframed[outerlinewidth=0pt,
  innerlinewidth=0pt,
  middlelinewidth=2pt,
  middlelinecolor=blue,
  bottomline=false,topline=false,rightline=false]{defi}

\newtheorem{dem}{Démonstration}
\surroundwithmdframed[outerlinewidth=0pt,
  innerlinewidth=0pt,
  middlelinewidth=2pt,
  middlelinecolor=violet,
  bottomline=false,topline=false,rightline=false]{dem}
  
\newtheorem{app}{Application}
\surroundwithmdframed[outerlinewidth=0pt,
  innerlinewidth=0pt,
  middlelinewidth=2pt,
  middlelinecolor=orange,
  bottomline=false,topline=false,rightline=false]{app}
  
\newtheorem{dev}{Développement}
\surroundwithmdframed[outerlinewidth=0pt,
  innerlinewidth=0pt,
  middlelinewidth=2pt,
  middlelinecolor=violet,
  bottomline=false,topline=false,rightline=false]{dev}
 
\newtheorem*{don}{Données}
\surroundwithmdframed[outerlinewidth=0pt,
  innerlinewidth=0pt,
  middlelinewidth=2pt,
  middlelinecolor=teal,
  bottomline=false,topline=false,rightline=false]{don}  
  

\newtheoremstyle{nonumber}{0pt}{3pt}{}{}{\itshape}{\phantom{}}{0pt}{}
\theoremstyle{nonumber} %Environnements thm non numérotés
\newtheorem*{law}{}
\surroundwithmdframed[outerlinewidth=0pt,
  innerlinewidth=0pt,
  middlelinewidth=2pt,
  middlelinecolor=red,
  bottomline=false,topline=false,rightline=false]{law}

\newtheorem*{rmq}{\textit{Remarque} : }

\date{}
```

I tried all i know about Latex but nothing had worked. My footer isn't on the page and don't take the all width of my document